# Move with possible rename

Tags: command-line, shell-script, rename

Is it possible to construct a command that will move the file to another directory and if the same file is already there, generate some random string that is not in the name of some file in the directory and rename the file to this random string?

I know the `mv -i` command, so I do it manually and files that are contained rename to something else.

thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mv -b file destination/
```

should do the trick.

```
mv --backup=TYPE
```

will act like the type says, it is either of the following:

```
none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
numbered, t     make numbered backups
existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
simple, never   always make simple backups
```

Comment: I tried it as follows `mv -b file destination/` . Now in the destination is `file` and `file~` . I have another file named `file`. I used the command `mv -b file destination/` and one file was lost, in destination there is only `file` and `file~`. I expected there will be `file~~` too.

Comment: Try: `mv --backup=numbered file destination/` instead.

Comment: Note that this renames the existing file at the destination, rather than creating a new name for the file being moved. (It's not clear whether this is acceptable for what you're asking)

Comment: @Random832 This is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard or common single-step command. Here's a two-step process, relying on the non-standard but common [`mktemp`](http://www.mktemp.org/).

```
tmp=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$destination") mktemp -t)
mv -- "$source" "$tmp"
echo n | mv -i -- "$tmp" "$destination"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mv -fv --backup=simple file1.txt archive/ 

‘file1.txt’ -> ‘archive/file1.txt’ (backup: ‘archive/file1.txt~’)

$ ll archive/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         8 Dec 10 11:06 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        10 Dec 10 11:05 file1.txt~
```

The mv above will move the file1.txt to archive/ directory and rename the existing archive/file1.txt to file1.txt~ in case of any file name conflict. It keeps only one backup file ‘archive/file1.txt~’ if you run it again.